# replace name after specific syntax

Tags: bash, awk, sed, regular-expression, perl

We have Bash script. We want to change the name - `master02` with `$machine_master` in the Bash script.

```
    value=master02_up
    #master02
    http://master02.$domain:8080
```

How to change `master02` to `$machine_master`, only if `master02` is after  `http://master02`.

Expected output:

```
    value=master02_up
    #master02
    http://$machine_master.$domain:8080
```

Comment: `awk '/http/ {sub(/master02/,"$machine_master")}1' file`

Comment: is `$machine_master` intended as variable or as literal string?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest From the expected output, it looks as if it's intended to be a fixed string.

Comment: @Kusalananda, there are many unexpected cases in comprehension of user questions. I feel like it's better to obtain the real "picture" through elaboration (even if something seems simple) (based on experience of working with SO and U&L)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using standard `sed`:

```
sed 's#http://master02.\$domain:8080#http://$machine_master.$domain:8080#' file >newfile
```

This replaces the exact string `http://master02.$domain:8080` with `http://$machine_master.$domain:8080` and writes the result to a new file.

The `$` in `$domain` has to be escaped to not be interpreted as an "end of line" pattern.  The `$` in the replacement text does not need to be escaped as this part is not a pattern.

I'm using `#` as a delimiter for the `sed` substitute command (`s`) as the pattern and replacement text both contain `/` which is the default delimiter.

The command could also be shortened to

```
sed 's#http://master02#http://$machine_master#' file >newfile
```

if it's safe to do so (this depends on the contents of the file and what instances of text you'd like to replace).

Testing:

```
$ cat file
value=master02_up
#master02
http://master02.$domain:8080

$ sed 's#http://master02.\$domain:8080#http://$machine_master.$domain:8080#' file >newfile

$ cat newfile
value=master02_up
#master02
http://$machine_master.$domain:8080
```